# Not working CefSharp.Handler.DialogHandler on Ctrl+O vscode.dev

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-code, cefsharp

I`m trying to handle OpenFolderDialog on [VS Code for Web](https://vscode.dev) using CefSharp WPF. But extending `CefSharp.Handler.DialogHandler` does not result in handling folder dialogue. There is a code example:

```
chromium = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
chromium.LoadingStateChanged += Chromium_LoadingStateChanged;
chromium.DialogHandler = new OFD();

    public class OFD : CefSharp.Handler.DialogHandler
        {
            public string path;

            protected override bool OnFileDialog(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, CefFileDialogMode mode, CefFileDialogFlags flags, string title, string defaultFilePath, List<string> acceptFilters, int selectedAcceptFilter, IFileDialogCallback callback)
            {
                callback.Continue(0, new List<string> { this.path });
                return false;
            }
        }
     private void Chromium_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, CefSharp.LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.IsLoading)
            {
                App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    if (chromium.Address != null)
                    {
                        if (chromium.Address.StartsWith("https://vscode.dev"))
                        {
                            chromium.Focus();
                            ((OFD)chromium.DialogHandler).path = @"E:\WebStormProjects\Monarch";
                            new InputSimulator().Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_O);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

I`ve also tried other handlers like `CefSharp.Handler.ResourceRequestHandler`, but no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? High level, not how you are trying to achieve it.

Comment: @amaitland , I need to build into my project JS-CSS-HTML IDE  for editing some structured web app subproject, that after a huge amount of processes will be compiled to my proprietary bundle with a dozen of other files

Comment: Is the OnFileDialog method being called? From memory you should be returning true to implement a custom behaviour. Have you tried manually pressing the key combination.?

Comment: @amaitland, no, `OnFileDialog()` is not being called at all. I know about `true` to implement custom behaviour, but it doesn't matter in my case at all. Manual pressing of key combination also not calling `OnFileDialog()`. I have achieved calling of `OnFileDialog()` only using `RunFileDialog()`, but [VS Code web](https://vscode.dev) does not react at all on selecting manually or programmatically a file or folder from the opened dialogue. It is very strange.

Comment: What version are you using? Upstream dialog support has been rewritten, if there is a bug hopefully it'll be resolved in version 102 see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/3314/use-chrome-file-dialogs-on-all-platforms for reference

Comment: I'm using 101.150, I'll wait to 102 to test, the link you gave me is precisely what I'm facing now. @amaitland, I'm interested in alpha and beta tests of 102, let me know when it is available

Comment: CI builds should be available early/mid next week. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp#releases-1

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue in Chrome Embed Framework version 101 and below, not only in CefSharp. I'll wait until the 102 version is released with file dialogue reworks and report here if this issue is resolved.